# error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi anyone know how do i fix this problem. trying to add level on my game.
anyone know which part of the code i need to change

```
protected SyncFieldString syncTitle = new SyncFieldString();

public virtual string Title
{
    get { return title; }
    set
    {
        title = value;
        if (IsServer)
            syncTitle.Value = value;
    }
}

protected SyncFieldString syncLevel = new SyncFieldString();

public virtual string Level
{
    get { return level; }
    set
    {
        level = value;
        if (IsServer)
            syncLevel.Value = value;
    }
}
```

And here some of the code in my level format

```
if (uiTextLevel != null)
    uiTextLevel.text = string.Format(levelFormat, Data == null ? "N/A" : Data.Level.ToString("N0"));
```

Sorry im just beginner.

Comment: You should provide more information on when and where the error occurs, what `SyncFieldString`, where `level` and `title` are defined is and so on. You should get answers faster then.

Comment: Take a very close and very stern look at the error message. What do you see, what do you read? The error message tells you in plain English _what_ you have done wrong. Also, the (complete) error message will also tell you in which code line of your project you made the error. If you look at that code line and you don't understand it fully, take a very close and stern look at the documentation of whatever methods/classes/etc are being used in that code line to get an understanding of how those methods/classes/etc should be used correctly...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Data.Level.ToString("N0")`? `Data.Level` already gives you a string